# FOIL Python's strong typing!

Tags: code-golf, python

Your task is to write some code in Python 2 or 3 such that this expression:

```
(a+b)(c+d) == a*c + b*c + a*d + b*d
```

will evaluate to `True` without raising any exceptions.

To clarify, I will copy your code into a file, then `from` the file `import *`. Then I will type the expression into the console and verify that it is `True`.

This is code-golf, so the answer with the shortest length (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### <del>54</del> <del>52</del> <del>50</del> <del>49</del> <del>48</del> <del>45</del> 39 bytes

Removed 4 bytes thanks to Dennis.

The latest version is inspired by the "some reason" in xnor's answer.

```
class t(int):__add__=type
a=b=t()
c=d=0
```

Comment: Nice! There's `0 .__mul__` for `lambda y:0` but it's the same length.

Comment: `x.count` saves a byte.

Comment: With `a=t();b=c=d=0`, you can use `class t(int):__add__=lambda*x:t` to save three bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks. Good idea...

Comment: I don't get it... `type(t(), t())` or `t().type(t())` throws an exception, so what is happening when you do `t() + t()`?

Comment: @feersum just `type(t())`. The LHS becomes `(type(b))(0)` or `t(0)`, which is equal to `0`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan But `+` is a binary operator. Why would `__add__` be called with 1 argument?

Comment: @feersum `__add__` is called with two, but the first is interpreted as `self`, only `other` is passed to `type`. Weird, yes.

Comment: @feersum The difference is, I believe, that inbuilts use method-wrappers (py3) or unbound methods (py2) (rather than methods or bound methods respectively, like `MySpam.__myEggs__` would usually be). I could well be wrong though, interested to know...

Comment: @JonathanAllan But try this: `numargs = lambda *a: len(a);    class t(int): __add__ = numargs`    `t() + t()` results in `2`!

Comment: @feersum: `a + b` first tries `a.__add__(b)`. `a.__add__` is `type`, so that becomes `type(b)`. The key difference between this case and the usual case for methods is that usually, `a.__add__` would be a different object from the thing you set `__add__` to in the class definition, due to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors), which ordinary function objects implement. (There are also a few other tricky bits that aren't relevant here.)

Answer (score 10):

### 54 bytes

```python
class m(int):__call__=__add__=lambda*x:m()
a=b=c=d=m()
```

Make an object that inherits from `int`, except adding or calling just returns a copy of itself.

Same length:

```python
class m(int):__call__=__add__=lambda a,b:a
a=b=c=d=m()
```

I thought `min` or `{}.get` would work in place of `lambda a,b:a`, but for some reason they act only on the second argument.

Comment: (it's [tag:code-golf])

Comment: Oops, I only saw [tag:programming-puzzle], will golf.

Comment: That was quite a reduction o-o

Comment: @xnor It doesn't work because `min` already has a `__self__` attribute, so the class skips binding its own self. Why `min` has `__self__` is another question...

Comment: @matsjoyce: No, it doesn't have anything to do with the fact that `min` has a `__self__`. `min.__self__` is just an artifact of how built-in functions and built-in methods are implemented as the same type. `min` doesn't work here because unlike functions written in Python, built-in functions don't support the descriptor protocol, which is responsible for binding the first argument.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, OK, I thought I got it working with sum yesterday, guess I was looking at wrong thing then.

Answer (score 3):

## <s>81</s> 66 bytes

```python
class e:__mul__=lambda*o:0;__add__=lambda*o:lambda x:0
a=b=c=d=e()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### 68 bytes

While it cannot really compete with the existing answers, this one actually performs the calculation in question:

```
from sympy.abc import*
type(a+b).__call__=lambda x,y:(x*y).expand()
```

Explanation:

- SymPy is a module for symbolic computations.
- `sympy.abc` contains all single-letter symbols, in particular ones named `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.
- `a+b` is an `Add` object, which represents a general sum.
- `type(a+b).__call__= […]` monkey-patches the `Add` class to give it evaluation capabilities, in this case enabling it to work like a multiplication of caller and callee.
- `expand` is necessary to make the expressions actually equal (since SymPy only performs thorough equality checks on demand).